# Controls .DataSource / .Databind not function correctly

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Just started a new ASP project and for some reason my drop down datasource and databind doesn't seem to be working properly when everything is there and no errors are thrown.

```
        List<ProductEntity> products = new List<ProductEntity>();
        ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager();

        products = productManager.GetProducts();

        ddlProducts.DataSource = products;
        ddlProducts.DataBind();
```

the asp code.

```
        int colCounter = 0;
        List<ProductEntity> products = new List<ProductEntity>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FIConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SV_GetProduct";


            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(dr = cmd.ExecuteReader());
            cn.Close();
        }
        foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
        {
            ProductEntity prod = new ProductEntity();
            foreach (DataColumn columns in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (colCounter == 0)
                {
                    prod.ProductDesc = Convert.ToString(rows[columns]);
                    colCounter++;
                }
                else if (colCounter == 1)
                {
                    prod.FormingCode = Convert.ToString(rows[columns]);
                    colCounter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return products;
```

and the GetProducts code.

When stepping through the project GetProducts successfully returns data. I am just unable to bind it even though everything looks to be in order. My attempt at databinding is on the Page Load even which I have done before but doesn't seem to be working this time. So confused, any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Did you set a value for the DataTextField and DataValueField properties?

Comment: I have and I get the same results

Answer (score 1):

Not completely understand your problem.
Also mention the following properties of dropdownlist ddl

`ddl.DataTextFeild="Feild to Display";
ddl.DataValueFeild="Feild ID";`

Comment: Ya, I just did that and I got it working, I also forgot to add to the list I was returning to in the Get function. Today is not a good day for me haha. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = GetProducts();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FormingCode";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ProductDesc";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

        private List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            List<Product> ret = new List<Product>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Product p = new Product();
                p.ProductDesc = i;
                p.FormingCode = i.ToString();
                ret.Add(p);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public string FormingCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```